# redirect from redux action in react router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I have used `react-router v4` for routing in my application. In homepage, there is a form. When user fills up form and hits the submit button, then the action is dispatched(showResultofCar) and it should be redirected to result page which is not a child in the homepage instead it is a different page with different UI from top to bottom.

I tried to do this way but the action is not dispatched only the routing has been transitioned but shows the same homepage instead of new page(result)

**index.js**

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <ConnectedIntlProvider>
      <Router>
        <App />
      </Router>
    </ConnectedIntlProvider>
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.app'));
```

**app.js**

```
render() {
  return (
      <div className="container-fluid">
        <Nav
          showModal={(e) => this.showModal(e)}
          hideModal={() => this.hideModal()}
          show={this.state.show}
          onHide={() => this.hideModal()}
        />
          <Banner />
          <Media />
          <Footer />
        </div>
        );
}
```

**form.js(it is a child component of banner which is a child component of app)**

```
onSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const originwithCountry = e.target.Origen.value;
  const originwithCity = originwithCountry.split(', ')[0];
  const cityFrom = base64.encode(originwithCity);
  const startDate = (new Date(e.target.startDate.value).getTime() / 1000);
  this.props.showResultofCar(cityFrom, cityTo, startDate);
  this.context.router.transitionTo('/result');
  }

render() {
  const { focusedInput } = this.state;
  const { intl } = this.props;
  return (
    <div className="form-box text-center">
      <div className="container">
        <form className="form-inline" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <Field
              name='Origen'
              component={renderGeoSuggestField}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <Field
              name="daterange"
              onFocusChange={this.onFocusChange}
            />
          </div>
          <Link to="/result">
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default buscar">
            { intl.formatMessage({ id: 'buscar.text' })}
          </button>
        </Link>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**result-parent.js**

```
class ResultParent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="result-page">
        <Match pattern='/result' component={Result} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**result.js**

```
class Result extends Component {
render() {
  return (
    <div className="result-page">
      <ResultNav />
      <Filtering />
      <Results />
    </div>
  );
}
}
```

**actions/index.js**

```
export function showResultofCar(cityFrom, cityTo, date) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: 'CAR_FETCH_START' });
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    console.log('date', date);
    return axios.get(`${API_URL}/car/{"cityFrom":"${cityFrom}","cityTo":"${cityTo}","date":${date}}.json/null/${token}`)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('response is', response);
        dispatch({ type: 'CAR_FETCH_SUCCESS', payload: response.data });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch({ type: 'CAR_FETCH_FAILURE', payload: err });
      });
  };
}
```

My way is not working. How can i now redirect using react router v4 inside action?

Also i don't want the result to be shown inside App component(parent) because result page will be completely different with its own navbar,filtering and results option.

**Note: React router v4 has been used**

Comment: Have a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31079244/4929834

Comment: I have tried but that way only the url gets changed. I dont get to the result page.

Comment: have you tried `this.context.router.push('/result');` instead of `transitionTo`?

Comment: there is no push in v4. push is available in history and i tried that too.

Comment: You aren't rendering `<ResultParent>` anywhere that I can see.

Comment: Where should i render it to show it in different page other than homepage?

Comment: For me the easiest solution was to add the `withRouter` HOC to the component then pass `this.props.history` from it to the action where you call `history.push('/route-name')`. [See this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42124328/1494454)

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is make a redirect handler inside of your **App.js**:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.handleRedirect = this.handleRedirect.bind(this);
  this.handleSubmitForm = this.handleSubmitForm.bind(this);
}

handleRedirect() {
  this.props.push('/result');
}

handleSubmitForm(cityFrom, cityTo, startDate) {
  this.props.showResultofCar(cityFrom, cityTo, startDate, this.handleRedirect);
}
...
```

And provide your Form component with **handleSubmitForm** through props. This way you won't have to connect Form component to Redux dispatch actions.

Inside of your **showResultofCar** action you can now call this redirect handler on Promise success:

```
export function showResultofCar(cityFrom, cityTo, date, redirectOnSuccess) {
  ...
    .then((response) => {
      // console.log('response is', response);
      dispatch({ type: 'CAR_FETCH_SUCCESS', payload: response.data });
      redirectOnSuccess();
    })
  ...
}
```

I know it might not be the *cleanest* way but it will do the work for you.