# Programmatically navigate using react router V4

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router-v4

I have just replaced `react-router` from v3 to v4.
But I am not sure how to programmatically navigate in the member function of a `Component`.
i.e in `handleClick()` function I want to navigate to `/path/some/where` after processing some data.
I used to do that by:

```js
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'
browserHistory.push('/path/some/where')
```

But I can't find such interfaces in v4.
How can I navigate using v4?

Comment: You can access the history object in v4 through props: this.props.history.push('/')

Comment: What if you want to access it from a different place than a `Component`? For example, inside the redux actions.

Comment: sometimes i  wondering why it is so complicated to just move from one link to the other =))

Comment: One would think that in this day and age redirecting wouldn't be so f'ing complicated.

Comment: I found this post helpful: https://medium.com/@anneeb/redirecting-in-react-4de5e517354a

Comment: simplest way https://stackoverflow.com/a/53916596/3966458

Answer (score 455, accepted):

If you are targeting browser environments, you need to use `react-router-dom` package, instead of `react-router`. They are following the same approach as React did, in order to separate the core, (`react`) and the platform specific code, (`react-dom`, `react-native` ) with the subtle difference that you don't need to install two separate packages, so the environment packages contain everything you need. You can add it to your project as:

`yarn add react-router-dom`

or

`npm i react-router-dom`

The first thing you need to do is to provide a `<BrowserRouter>` as the top most parent component in your application. `<BrowserRouter>` uses the HTML5 `history` API and manages it for you, so you don't have to worry about instantiating it yourself and passing it down to the `<BrowserRouter>` component as a prop (as you needed to do in previous versions).

In V4, for navigating programatically you need to access the `history` object, which is available through React `context`, as long as you have a `<BrowserRouter>` *provider* component as the top most parent in your application. The library exposes through context the `router` object, that itself contains `history` as a property. The `history` interface offers several navigation methods, such as `push`, `replace` and `goBack`, among others. You can check the whole list of properties and methods [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history).

### Important Note to Redux/Mobx users


**If you are using redux or mobx as your state management library in your application, you may have come across issues with components that should be location-aware but are not re-rendered after triggering an URL update**

That's happening because `react-router` passes `location` to components using the context model.

> Both connect and observer create components whose shouldComponentUpdate methods do a shallow comparison of their current props and their next props. Those components will only re-render when at least one prop has changed. This means that in order to ensure they update when the location changes, they will need to be given a prop that changes when the location changes.

The 2 approaches for solving this are:

- Wrap your *connected* component in a pathless `<Route />`. The current `location` object is one of the props that a `<Route>` passes to the component it renders
- Wrap your *connected* component with the `withRouter` higher-order component, that in fact has the same effect and injects `location` as a prop

Setting that aside, there are four ways to navigate programatically, ordered by recommendation:

#### 1.- Using a `<Route>` Component

 It promotes a declarative style. Prior to v4, `<Route />` components were placed at the top of your component hierarchy, having to think of your routes structure beforehand. However, now you can have `<Route>` components **anywhere** in your tree, allowing you to have a finer control for conditionally rendering depending on the URL. `Route` injects `match`, `location` and `history` as props into your component. The navigation methods (such as `push`, `replace`, `goBack`...) are available as properties of the `history` object.

There are 3 ways to render something with a `Route`, by using either `component`, `render` or `children` props, but don't use more than one in the same `Route`. The choice depends on the use case, but basically the first two options will only render your component if the `path` matches the url location, whereas with `children` the component will be rendered whether the path matches the location or not (useful for adjusting the UI based on URL matching).

**If you want to customise your component rendering output**, you need to wrap your component in a function and use the `render` option, in order to pass to your component any other props you desire, apart from `match`, `location` and `history`. An example to illustrate:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom'

const ButtonToNavigate = ({ title, history }) => (
  <button
    type="button"
    onClick={() => history.push('/my-new-location')}
  >
    {title}
  </button>
);

const SomeComponent = () => (
  <Route path="/" render={(props) => <ButtonToNavigate {...props} title="Navigate elsewhere" />} />
)    

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <SomeComponent /> // Notice how in v4 we can have any other component interleaved
    <AnotherComponent />
  </Router>
);
```

#### 2.- Using `withRouter` HoC

This higher order component will inject the same props as `Route`. However, it carries along the limitation that you can have only 1 HoC per file.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

const ButtonToNavigate = ({ history }) => (
  <button
    type="button"
    onClick={() => history.push('/my-new-location')}
  >
    Navigate
  </button>
);


ButtonToNavigate.propTypes = {
  history: React.PropTypes.shape({
    push: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  }),
};

export default withRouter(ButtonToNavigate);
```

#### 3.- Using a `Redirect` component

Rendering a `<Redirect>` will navigate to a new location. But keep in mind that, **by default**, the current location is replaced by the new one, like server-side redirects (HTTP 3xx). The new location is provided by `to` prop, that can be a string (URL to redirect to) or a `location` object. If you want to **push a new entry onto the history** instead, pass a `push` prop as well and set it to `true`

```
<Redirect to="/your-new-location" push />
```

#### 4.- Accessing `router` manually through context

A bit discouraged because [context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html) is still an experimental API and it is likely to break/change in future releases of React

```
const ButtonToNavigate = (props, context) => (
  <button
    type="button"
    onClick={() => context.router.history.push('/my-new-location')}
  >
    Navigate to a new location
  </button>
);

ButtonToNavigate.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.shape({
    history: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  }),
};
```

Needless to say there are also other Router components that are meant to be for non browser ecosystems, such as `<NativeRouter>` that replicates a navigation stack *in memory* and targets React Native platform, available through `react-router-native` package.

For any further reference, don't hesitate to take a look at the [official docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/). There is also a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a4kqMQorcnE) made by one of the co-authors of the library that provides a pretty cool introduction to react-router v4, highlighting some of the major changes.

Comment: It seems that `v4` does not have `withRouter`

Comment: I am using V4 and the above works fine. I have spent a fair bit of time mucking about with the V4 router as there seems some strange choices but the above definitely works. I assume you are importing `withRouter` from `react-router-dom`

Comment: As Sam states, I was gonna point that out, just updated my answer to make that clear

Comment: I am importing `withRouter` from `react-router-dom`. The history.push does change the url, but it does not seem to load the `<Route>` until I force refresh the page ...

Comment: Could you share some code through a repo or snippet?

Comment: @rauliyohmc I was wrong about this. The problem is that I have `<Router>`  inside a React component who is decorated with `@observer`, which triggers [this issue](https://github.com/mobxjs/mobx-react/issues/210). The work around is to have `@withRouter` on every such React component.

Comment: That's right @BreakDS, the same happens with redux `@connect` decorator. I updated my answer to reflect that, since it seems to be a common issue right now for new users.

Comment: For those who come across this great answer, `withRouter` is simply a HOC that uses a `Route` under the hood. Which means that it only uses [3 props, history, match, and location](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/Route-props). In the example above it appears that `push` is a prop that `withRouter` would add to `ButtonToNavigate`, but that is not the case. `props.history.push` would have to be used instead. Hope this helps others who were a bit confused.

Comment: Great catch, my original response was based on the alpha version, in which `withRouter` received different props. I see that changed in the final official release, will update to avoid further confusions :)

Comment: In the first example, you say that "you can pass to Route any other props you desire, so that your component will receive them.". In the latest production version 4.0 of react-router this does not seem to be the case. Based on my tests, and the documentation (https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/Route-props) the only three properties that get passed to the component are match, location, and history.

Comment: There is a way to work that around, and that is using the `render` prop in a `<Route />`, take a look at the updated 1st example

Comment: Wow. `browserHistory.push('/path/some/where')` just seems to much simpler. The authors are trying to discourage imperative programming, but sometimes it just works better!

Comment: thanks for that answer - it should be a part of docs in my opinion

Comment: That note about wrapping the connected component in a Route is so incredibly helpful.

Comment: The easy way is to use the histroy.
this.props.history.push('/some/path')

Comment: Could you please update the code in this post? PropTypes cannot be found anymore in React main package, would need (after npm install prop-types): import PropTypes from 'prop-types'; and   history: PropTypes.shape({
    push: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  })

Comment: The video link is dead. Any chance it's still available somewhere?

Comment: Btw `PropTypes` for history object injected using `withRouter` decorator doesn't work. Throws undefined for the whole history

Answer (score 170):

The easiest way to get it done:

`this.props.history.push("/new/url")`

Note:

- You may want to pass the `history` `prop` from parent component down to the component you want to invoke the action if its not available.

Comment: I use 4.0 router, but there is no history key on props. How can I fix it?

Comment: If you don't have `this.props.history` available in your component then you can `import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'` and then  `export default withRouter(MyComponent)` (or `const MyComponent = withRouter(...)`) and it will insert the `history` item in your component's props.

Comment: @Malvineous thats interesting, didn't know about this! Will try it!

Comment: I must be missing something fundamental, because this works just great for me so I have no idea why all the answers require such lengthy explanations.

Comment: how to prevent component remount on `history.push` and just trigger update like when we click on `<Link>`

Comment: The best answer was: this.props.history.push("/new/url")

Comment: The confusion comes from the fact that this only really works in a Class based approach. It doesn't work quite the same way in a functional approach because `this` isn't bound and props aren't accessible in that way. In a functional approach, you just need to start at the `history` object and use `history.push('/path')`.

Comment: As of v6 you're supposed to use `useNavigate` https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#use-usenavigate-instead-of-usehistory

Answer (score 59):

I had a similar issue when migrating over to React-Router v4 so I'll try to explain my solution below.

Please do not consider this answer as the right way to solve the problem, I imagine there's a good chance something better will arise as React Router v4 becomes more mature and leaves beta (It may even already exist and I just didn't discover it).

For context, I had this problem because I occasionally use `Redux-Saga` to programmatically change the history object (say when a user successfully authenticates).

In the React Router docs, take a look at the `<Router>` [component](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/#router) and you can see you have the ability to pass your own history object via a prop. This is the essence of the solution - **we supply the history object** to `React-Router` from a ***global*** module.

### Steps:

1. Install the history npm module - `yarn add history` **or** `npm install history --save`
2. create a file called `history.js` in your `App.js` level folder (this was my preference)

   ```
   // src/history.js

   import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
   export default createHistory();`
   ```
3. Add this history object to your Router component like so

   ```
   // src/App.js

   import history from '../your/path/to/history.js;'
   <Router history={history}>
   // Route tags here
   </Router>
   ```
4. Adjust the URL just like before by importing **your** global history object:

   ```
   import history from '../your/path/to/history.js;'
   history.push('new/path/here/');
   ```

Everything should stay synced up now, and you also have access to a way of setting the history object programmatically and not via a component/container.

Comment: This change worked for me, but only because I'm navigating outside of a component. If I was navigating inside a component like the OP, I would use the approach suggested by @rauliyohmc by using the props passed down by the `Route` component.

Comment: this is the recommended approach as of 08/17

Comment: @Spets In my case, if I use this kind of approach, the link will be updated properly after the push, but the components are not rendered properly (eg, after updating the link, component is not updated unless you force page refresh). Where did you find that this is recommended approach? Any links/sources?

Comment: @cool I was just reading this page on blocking issues with redux, have you seen it? https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/guides/dealing-with-update-blocking

Comment: @ScottCoates I sorted out using the example above, indeed by providing the history as a parameter, but after I did debug of the node modules by myself. There is a common mistake made all around the web, using import of "BrowserHistory as Router", when instead there is another object called Router by itself in the latest version of the react-router-dom. Using that in combination with history created in example above works just fine.

Comment: @cool this is all over the github issues page as the solution.

Glad you're able to solve it, there are a few quarks with the migration and snags but yeah its from react-router the low level library and not react-router-dom

Comment: Man..., #4 was the one i was looking for, as i my Meteor rendered page had multiple React Roots, and i was going crazy on how to trigger navigation from a component inside the second root. This is just perfect. Days of frustration are gone..

Comment: the url is updated, but the page is not renderd based on the new root. Any solution? Why trigger route is so difficult? People who design react is out of their mind?

Comment: Same, location bar is updating to new path but nothing is being rendered.

Answer (score 50):

TL;DR:

```
if (navigate) {
  return <Redirect to="/" push={true} />
}
```

**The simple and declarative answer is that you need to use `<Redirect to={URL} push={boolean} />` in combination with `setState()`**

> **push: boolean -** when true, redirecting will push a new entry onto the history instead of replacing the current one.

---

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router'

class FooBar extends React.Component {
  state = {
    navigate: false
  }

  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.state

    // here is the important part
    if (navigate) {
      return <Redirect to="/" push={true} />
    }
   // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.setState({ navigate: true })}>
          Home
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Full example [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow).
Read more [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect).

*PS. The example uses [ES7+ Property Initializers](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#es7-property-initializers) to initialise state. Look [here](https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/06/07/react-on-es6-plus) as well, if you're interested.*

Comment: This should be accepted answer. Simplest elegant solution! +1 for @lustoykov

Comment: I also set navigate back to false in componentDidUpdate as my button is in a header and would otherwise only navigate once.

Comment: This only works if you know about the redirect when the page loads. If you're waiting for an asynchronous call to return (i.e. authentication with Google or something) then you'll have to use one of the `history.push()` methods.

Comment: Not really, you can still leverage the declarative nature of react combined with the <Redirect /> component. If the page does not load, you can fallback to another <Redirect />

Comment: @brittohalloran the idea of this method using the proper react router, is to make sure you use setState to force a re-render.

Comment: Pretty sure you need to set navigate to false afterwards otherwise it will try to redirect multiple times (depending on your component structure of course)

Answer (score 43):

## Use `useHistory` hook if you're using function components

You can use [`useHistory`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory) hook to get `history` instance.

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const MyComponent = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  
  return (
    <button onClick={() => history.push("/about")}>
      Click me
    </button>
  );
}
```

The `useHistory` hook gives you access to the history instance that you may use to navigate.

## Use `history` property inside page components

React Router injects some properties including `history` to page components.

```
class HomePage extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { history } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => history.push("/projects")}>
          Projects
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

## Wrap child components [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter) to inject router properties

`withRouter` wrapper injects router properties to components. For example you can use this wrapper to inject router to logout button component placed inside user menu.

```
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

const LogoutButton = withRouter(({ history }) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={() => history.push("/login")}>
      Logout
    </button>
  );
});

export default LogoutButton;
```

Answer (score 12):

You can also simply use props to access history object: `this.props.history.push('new_url')`

Comment: Useful only when in the component directly descended from the Router. Lest you pass the history prop to every single component you need this functionality in.

Comment: If you don't have `this.props.history` available in your component then you can `import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'` and then  `export default withRouter(MyComponent)` (or `const MyComponent = withRouter(...)`) and it will insert the `history` item in your component's props.

Answer (score 10):

Step 1: There is only one thing to import on top:

```
import {Route} from 'react-router-dom';
```

Step 2: In your Route, pass the history:

```
<Route
  exact
  path='/posts/add'
  render={({history}) => (
    <PostAdd history={history} />
  )}
/>
```

Step 3: history gets accepted as part of props in the next Component, so you can simply:

```
this.props.history.push('/');
```

That was easy and really powerful.

Answer (score 8):

My answer is similar to [Alex's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42320249/65387). I'm not sure why React-Router made this so needlessly complicated. Why should I have to wrap my component with a HoC just to get access to what's essentially a global?

Anyway, if you take a look at how they implemented [`<BrowserRouter>`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/d601722f8515eea3910bb3a69313f3f2fc37df16/packages/react-router-dom/modules/BrowserRouter.js), it's just a tiny wrapper around [history](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history).

We can pull that history bit out so that we can import it from anywhere. The trick, however, is if you're doing server-side rendering and you try to `import` the history module, it won't work because it uses browser-only APIs. But that's OK because we usually only redirect in response to a click or some other client-side event. Thus it's probably OK to fake it:

```
// history.js
if(__SERVER__) {
    module.exports = {};
} else {
    module.exports = require('history').createBrowserHistory();
}
```

With the help of webpack, we can define some vars so we know what environment we're in:

```
plugins: [
    new DefinePlugin({
        '__SERVER__': 'false',
        '__BROWSER__': 'true', // you really only need one of these, but I like to have both
    }),
```

And now you can

```
import history from './history';
```

From anywhere. It'll just return an empty module on the server.

If you don't want use these magic vars, you'll just have to `require` in the global object where it's needed (inside your event handler). `import` won't work because it only works at the top-level.

Comment: damn they made it so complicated.

Comment: I totally agreed with you. this is so complicated for just a navigation

Answer (score 8):

I think that @rgommezz covers most of the cases minus one that I think it's quite important.

```
// history is already a dependency or React Router, but if don't have it then try npm install save-dev history

import createHistory from "history/createBrowserHistory"

// in your function then call add the below 
const history = createHistory();
// Use push, replace, and go to navigate around.
history.push("/home");
```

This allows me to write a simple service with actions/calls that I can call to do the navigation from any component I want without doing a lot HoC on my components...

It is not clear why nobody has provided this solution before. I hope it helps, and if you see any issue with it please let me know.

Comment: Love the thought BUT I can't get anything to re-render on route changes. (I use `@withRouter` to decorate any components that depend on the route). Any ideas?

Comment: Oh I'm using v5 maybe that's the issue.

Answer (score 7):

This works:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const SomeComponent = withRouter(({ history }) => (
    <div onClick={() => history.push('/path/some/where')}>
        some clickable element
    </div>); 
);

export default SomeComponent;
```

Answer (score 7):

You can navigate conditionally by this way

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

function HomeButton() {
  const history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    history.push("/path/some/where");
  }

  return (
    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Go home
    </button>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I've been testing v4 for a few days now and .. I'm loving it so far! It just makes sense after a while.

I also had the same question and I found handling it like the following worked best (and might even be how it is intended). It uses state, a ternary operator and `<Redirect>`.

In the constructor()

```
this.state = {
    redirectTo: null
} 
this.clickhandler = this.clickhandler.bind(this);
```

In the render()

```
render(){
    return (
        <div>
        { this.state.redirectTo ?
            <Redirect to={{ pathname: this.state.redirectTo }} /> : 
            (
             <div>
               ..
             <button onClick={ this.clickhandler } />
              ..
             </div>
             )
         }
```

In the clickhandler()

```
 this.setState({ redirectTo: '/path/some/where' });
```

Hope it helps. Let me know.

Comment: Are there any pitfalls with this method? In my project with works only when I  set state in constructor, from there I can redirect to any page I want. But when I set state on event (props did change, for example) I see render method called with new state, but redirect don't happen I see same page

Comment: Pitfall is that it will replace the history, so you won't be able to hit back - so basically, this is not a good solution.

Answer (score 5):

I struggled with this for a while - something so simple, yet so complicated, because ReactJS is just a completely different way of writing web applications, it's very alien to us older folk!

I created a separate component to abstract the mess away:

```
// LinkButton.js

import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import {Route} from 'react-router-dom';

export default class LinkButton extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Route render={({history}) => (
                <button {...this.props}
                       onClick={() => {
                           history.push(this.props.to)
                       }}>
                    {this.props.children}
                </button>
            )}/>
        );
    }
}

LinkButton.propTypes = {
    to: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

Then add it to your `render()` method:

```
<LinkButton className="btn btn-primary" to="/location">
    Button Text
</LinkButton>
```

Comment: I find this solution quite useful. I'm copying the code. Let me know you put it on github - I'll directly attribute it to you.

Answer (score 4):

Since there's no other way to deal with this horrible design, I wrote a generic component that uses the `withRouter` [HOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html) approach. The example below is wrapping a `button` element, but you can change to any clickable element you need:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const NavButton = (props) => (
  <Button onClick={() => props.history.push(props.to)}>
    {props.children}
  </Button>
);

NavButton.propTypes = {
  history: PropTypes.shape({
    push: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }),
  to: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};

export default withRouter(NavButton);
```

Usage:

```
<NavButton to="/somewhere">Click me</NavButton>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
this.props.history.push("/url")
```

If you have not found this.props.history available in your component , 
then try this

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
export default withRouter(MyComponent)
```

Answer (score 3):

As sometimes I prefer to switch routes by Application then by buttons, this is a minimal working example what works for me:

```
import { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from 'react-router-dom'

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    /** @type BrowserRouter */
    this.router = undefined
  }

  async handleSignFormSubmit() {
    await magic()
    this.router.history.push('/')
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router ref={ el => this.router = el }>
        <Link to="/signin">Sign in</Link>
        <Route path="/signin" exact={true} render={() => (
          <SignPage onFormSubmit={ this.handleSignFormSubmit } />
        )} />
      </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who require to redirect before fully initalizing a router using `React Router` or `React Router Dom` You can provide a redirect by simply accesing the history object and pushing a new state onto it within your constructur of `app.js`.  Consider the following:

```
function getSubdomain(hostname) {
    let regexParse = new RegExp('[a-z\-0-9]{2,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,5}$');
    let urlParts = regexParse.exec(hostname);
    return hostname.replace(urlParts[0], '').slice(0, -1);
}

class App extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);


        this.state = {
            hostState: true
        };

        if (getSubdomain(window.location.hostname).length > 0) {
            this.state.hostState = false;
            window.history.pushState('', '', './login');
        } else {
            console.log(getSubdomain(window.location.hostname));
        }

    }


    render() {
        return (

            <BrowserRouter>
                {this.state.hostState ? (
                    <div>
                        <Route path="/login" component={LoginContainer}/>
                        <Route path="/" component={PublicContainer}/>
                    </div>
                ) : (
                    <div>
                        <Route path="/login" component={LoginContainer}/>
                    </div>
                )

                }
            </BrowserRouter>)
    }


}
```

Here we want to change the output Routes dependant on a subdomain, by interacting with the history object before the component renders we can effectively redirect while still leaving our routes in tact.

```
window.history.pushState('', '', './login');
```