# React Router v4 not displaying components

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-router, react-router-v4

The component is not been displayed when I navigate to localhost:3000/signup
Is it because react router is updated to v4 and they way you route in react has now changed?

I have my `main.js` file

```
import Signup from '../imports/ui/Signup';

import
const routes = (
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/signup" component={Signup}/>
  </Router>
);
```

Signup component

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Signup extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <p>Signup</p>
  }
}
```

I'm using react router v4, also using Meteor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically navigate using react router V4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123261/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router-v4)

Comment: @Dez thanks. So can I just install react-router-dom now with react-router v4 and the code should still work?

Comment: I switched to react-router v3 and it's working perfect with code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React Router v4 is a re-write of React Router so you'll have to read the new API and adjust your code accordingly. I suggest going through all the examples which can be found [here](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web). Here's the basic example that looks similar to your code. The biggest thing you'll notice is you no longer have a centralized route config. Instead, you render `` s dynamically when you need them.

```
import React from 'react'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link
} from 'react-router-dom'

const BasicExample = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><Link to="/">Home</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
        <li><Link to="/topics">Topics</Link></li>
      </ul>

      <hr/>

      <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
      <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
      <Route path="/topics" component={Topics}/>
    </div>
  </Router>
)

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Home</h2>
  </div>
)

const About = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>About</h2>
  </div>
)

const Topics = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h2>Topics</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/rendering`}>
          Rendering with React
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/components`}>
          Components
        </Link>
      </li>
      <li>
        <Link to={`${match.url}/props-v-state`}>
          Props v. State
        </Link>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <Route path={`${match.url}/:topicId`} component={Topic}/>
    <Route exact path={match.url} render={() => (
      <h3>Please select a topic.</h3>
    )}/>
  </div>
)

const Topic = ({ match }) => (
  <div>
    <h3>{match.params.topicId}</h3>
  </div>
)

export default BasicExample
```

Comment: Thank you Tyler, I will give this a go. It's alot different to v3.

Comment: You're very welcome. It is quite different and will take some time to get used to, but once you're used to it, I think you'll love it. Feel free to reach out if you get stuck.