# Unable to redirect programmatically with react-router 4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, react-router, react-router-v4

I've read a lot of docs and SOF questions about this subject I used a lot of methods to do this but none of them worked in a way I need. I suppose I am missing something important. It's hard to provide detailed and relevant code on every navigation method I used, I'll try it.

Here some introdactory imformation. I had react-redux app, I need to get state from server and redirect to page according to this state.

Simplified version of my App class render method:

```
 render() {
    console.log("App.render");
    console.log(this.state);
    return (

      <div id='game-container' width="1126" height="634">
        <Router>
        <div>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Page1}/>
          <Route path="/bets" component={Page2}/>
          <Route path="/games" component={Page3}/>
          <Route path="/newpage" component={Page4}/>
          <Route path="/info" component={ Info }/>
        </div>
        </Router>
        <Overlay/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

App component wrapped with BrowserRouter in index.js file

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={myStore}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App assets={ assets } locale={ qs['locale']} token={ qs['token']} sounds={ sounds } />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.game-wrapper'));
```

**Method 1. withRouter**

For it's realisation I added this code:

```
  App.propTypes = {
      history: React.PropTypes.shape({
      push: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
      }).isRequired,
      location: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    };


function mapStateToProps(state) {
    console.log("app#mapStateToProps");
    console.log(state.session);
    return { session:  state.session }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({ fetchInitialSession }, dispatch);
}

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchInitialSession })(App));
```

and then when  I am getting session info I try:

```
 this.props.history.push("/newpage");
```

url in browser is changing but visual page does not.

**Method 2. with context router**

For this just added

```
App.contextTypes = {
  router: React.PropTypes.object
};
```

and then when  I am getting session info I try:

```
 this.context.router.history.push("/newpage");
```

Same result as with first method (url is changed but page doesn't).

**Method 3. Redirect** (found here [Programmatically navigate using react router V4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123261/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router-v4))

So my render method looks like this:

```
render() {
    console.log("App.render");
    console.log(this.state);
    return (

      <div id='game-container' width="1126" height="634">
        <Router>
        <div>
      <Redirect to={{ pathname: this.state.redirectTo }}/>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Page1}/>
          <Route path="/bets" component={Page2}/>
          <Route path="/games" component={Page3}/>
          <Route path="/newpage" component={Page4}/>
          <Route path="/info" component={ Info }/>
        </div>
        </Router>
        <Overlay/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And when I want to change page I set new state:

```
this.setState({ redirectTo: "/newpage" });
```

This method gives strange  results. When I set initial state in constructor it redirects to any page. But when I use this method anywhere in code I see in debug that render method called with my new state but redirect never happens!

Comment: When you are trying to set the state, component is already mounted. Why not to use `history.push` instead of changing the state?

Comment: Did you read about my 1 and 2 methods?

Comment: Let's start from the page path. You are trying to open something by `/newpage` path, but you haven't specified it anywhere. Where are you handling it?

Comment: Sorry I did some adjustments when posted code here, /newpage specified, edited my question

Comment: The code you posted doesn't look like it will work at all. Where is `<Router>` in your `App` component coming from and isn't that a redundancy since you already have `<BrowserRouter>` in your `index.js`? I would suggest making a simpler example with complete code including your `require` statements so we can reproduce on our end to debug it.

Comment: When I remove Router tags from App render, everything works (except redirect), so it's redundant I agree. But when I remove BrowserRouter from index.js, I am getting error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'route' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In v4 method 3 should be the correct method (using the `Redirect` component). The problem you're having seems to be because `Redirect` only takes effect the first time it's mounted but you put Redirect at the top level in your router and it only gets mounted once.

So if you render `<Redirect to={{ pathname: this.state.redirectTo }}/>` it will only redirect the very first time it's rendered, but it won't redirect if you update the state using:

```
this.setState({ redirectTo: "/newpage" });
```

This is why it only worked for you when you set the `redirectTo` in the constructor but didnt redirect again after that.

Instead you're probably going to have to use `Redirect` in every component/route you want to trigger a redirect, it's not as tedious as it sounds though because you can just create a custom route component to use instead of the typical `Route` component and handle all the redirect logic once in your custom component.

You can find an example here where a `PrivateRoute` and  `PublicRoute` are used instead of the normal `Route` to check if the user is logged in and redirect accordingly:
https://github.com/tylermcginnis/react-router-firebase-auth/blob/master/src/components/index.js

Here's how the PrivateRoute which should only be accessible to logged in users looks like:

```
function PrivateRoute ({component: Component, authed, ...rest}) {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) => authed === true
        ? <Component {...props} />
        : <Redirect to={{pathname: '/login', state: {from: props.location}}} />}
    />
  )
}
```