# updating router's history location by dispatching redux action (using react-router-dom)

Tags: redux, react-router-dom

I have a router that looks something like this

```
<Router>
       <Switch>
             <Route path="abc.do" render={() => <SetupAppInitialLoad pageKey="abc" />} />
              <Route path="xyz.do" render={() => <SetupAppInitialLoad pageKey="xyz" />} />
       </Switch>
</Router>
```

I have many `Route` like these inside `<Switch>`. I am using redux to handle state and dispatching async actions from some components when user clicks on a button/link.

```
export const asyncExampleAction = () => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        //logic to send inputs to server comes here
        .then(checkStatus)
        .then(parseJSON)
        .then( (data) => {
            if (success case) {
                history.push(`something.do?phase=something`);
            } else {
                //handle error logic
            }
        })
        .catch( (error) => {
            console.log(error);

        });
    }
}
```

Now, the problem I am facing is, even though history.push updates the url and navigates me to 'something.do?phase=something', but I don't see Route's history.location getting updated. Because of this (I think), when I click on some link on the page 'something.do?phase=something', only url of the page changes, but navigation to that new page doesn't happen.

I checked [Programmatically navigate using react router V4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123261/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router-v4) and [Programmatically navigate using react router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router?rq=1), but still not getting anywhere. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

That happens because `react-router` does not directly depend on `window.history`, but instead uses [this `history` project](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history), which wraps `window.history` and provides `react-router` with the possibility to listen to location updates and react on them.

You have to options to update navigate from your actions:

1. Use [react-router-redux](https://github.com/reacttraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux) library.
2. Or pass `history` prop from your `Component` to your `actions` and use it to navigate inside of them.

Second option is the one officialy recommended by [`react-router` doc](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/guides/redux-integration/deep-integration):

> Rather than dispatching actions to navigate you can pass the history object provided to route components to your actions and navigate with it there.

Comment: how to make "history" prop accessible to my component. When I debug my component using react dev tool, I don't see history in the list of its props. Can you point me to any working example where this approach has been implemented?