# React router "context.router.transitionTo is not a function"

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I am using 
**"react-router": "^4.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",**
All I am trying to do is when I submit form in one page it has to direct to the another defined page(component). Here is my code

**FormValue.js**

```
import React from "react";

class FormValues extends React.Component{
  gotoStore(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    let id = this.storeInput.value;
    this.context.router.transitionTo(`${id}`);
 }

render(){
    return (
            <form onSubmit={(e) => this.gotoStore(e)}>
                <input type="text" placeholder="enter your name" 
                 ref={(input) => {this.storeInput = input}}/>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
    )
}
}

FormValues.contextTypes = {
 router: React.PropTypes.object
}

 export default FormValues;
```

**index.js**

```
  import React from "react";
  import { render } from 'react-dom';
  import {BrowserRouter, Route} from "react-router-dom";
  import ReactDom from "react-dom";
  import App from './App';
  import FormValues from './FormValues';

  const Root = () => {
   return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <Route path="/" exact component={FormValues}/>
            <Route path="/:id" exact component={App}/>

        </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
   )
  }

  ReactDom.render(<Root/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

and I am getting error as [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLgRK.png)

any help would be appreciated

Comment: see this answer for navigating programatically, React doesn't recommend using context, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127739/programatically-navigate-using-react-router/44128108#44128108

Comment: I recognize Wes Bos' "React for beginners" course here. Today I stumbled on the same issue, how did You solved yours?

Comment: this thread contains a lot of useful information about programmatically navigation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123261/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router-v4

Answer (score 2):

My solution is:

```
import { PropTypes } from 'prop-types';

goToStore(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 const storeId = this.storeInput.value;
 this.props.history.push(`store/${storeId}`);
}

StorePicker.contextTypes = {
  router: PropTypes.object
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we can already access `history` under `props`, we don't even need to import `PropTypes` anymore. If you notice, when calling `this.props.history` we're not even touching the router context we declare later with `PropTypes`. Simply having the below code as is works:

```
goToStore(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 const storeId = this.storeInput.value;
 this.props.history.push(`store/${storeId}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { PropTypes } from "prop-types";

  goToStore(event) {

     event.preventDefault();

     const storeId = this.storeInput.value;

     this.context.router.history.push(`/store/${storeId}`);

  };

  StorePicker.contextTypes = {

    router: function contextType(){

     return PropTypes.object;

    }
  }
```