# CORS issue while trying to redirect from POST method to frontend page with GET request

Tags: javascript, php, web, cors

I would like to redirect from POST method to frontend page with HTTP status code 303.
Expected result is that browser after making POST request redirects to page specified in Location header.
Currently I am getting CORS failed error message and browser does not redirect to frontend page.

[image]

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I had, but I have added little more clarification in this question.

Comment: I am making request to api.local but that is the purpose of it, I need to call that api method and that method should redirect to frontend page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A redirect does not mean "Load this URL in the browser window". It means "You can get whatever you asked for here".

When you make an Ajax request using JavaScript, the response is provided to JavaScript.

If the response is a redirect, then the browser follows it automatically and provides the response to the redirect *to JavaScript*.

The URL you redirect to needs permission from CORS in order for the JavaScript to read the response.

---

**Do not attempt to mix web services and regular page navigation**

If you want to submit some data and load a new page: Use a form submission.

If you want to submit some data and handle the response with JS: Use Ajax.

Comment: Thank you for answering this question and with help of this answer and this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46514522/reactjs-sent-get-request-responded-with-302-redirect-received-cors-error I have managed to solve this issue.