# Access to fetch at https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth has been blocked by CORS

Tags: reactjs, express, oauth-2.0, cors, google-oauth

I'm sending fetch from React to Express to authenticate with Google but I've been getting access blocked by CORS error. I'm redirecting the POST request from React to the Google URL for authentication. I tried using cors in the express app but I'm still getting the same error.
For fetching

```
const handleClick = (e) => {
    fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/mail/login', {
        method: 'POST'
    })
    .then(res => res.text())
}
```

Using cors in express app.js

```
app.use(cors())
```

Trying to redirect to google auth

```
const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
    process.env.REDIRECT_URI
)

const url = oauth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: process.env.SCOPE
})

const gmail = google.gmail({
    version: 'v1',
    auth: oauth2Client
})

router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    res.redirect(url)
})
```

The error: Access to fetch at 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2F&response_type=code&client_id=727520060136-ngpfd4ll798v42gfclh7cms9ndqstt32.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000' (redirected from 'http://localhost:8000/api/mail/login') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: Seems pretty similar to this question, have you tried to implement their solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48925165/cors-issue-with-google-oauth2-for-server-side-webapps ?

Comment: Authorization worked with Express by itself using the google api library and redirects to the authorization page. I'm not sure why it breaks when I send the fetch from React to Express, and Express to Google

Comment: Honestly I don't know, I suggest you add more tags relating to the library you're trying to use, to make it easier for specialists of this google product to find your question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The authentication flow must happen in a visible [browsing context](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#windows), not with a `fetch` request. In other words: You must [*navigate*](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#navigation-request) the current tab to (or open a new tab at) http://localhost:8000/api/mail/login, the tab will then be redirected to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?... and this page becomes visible. Now the user must interact with that page to choose/confirm their Google account, after which they will be redirected to a page on your server with an authorization code in the URL (for example, http://localhost:8000/callback?code=...) and your server must exchange the authorization code for an access token with a server-to-server call.

When made like this, none of the requests made is cross-origin, so no CORS will be involved at all.

Instead of the `handleClick` function, you need a login form like

```html
<form action="http://localhost:8000/api/mail/login" method="post">
  <input type="submit" value="Press to log in"/>
</form>
```

Comment: That does not seem similar, then, but merits a separate question.

Comment: You cannot navigate with an authentication header, so this makes a big difference.

Comment: Maybe I should ask a different question: can you direct me towards a good resource that explains how a fetch is different from a form action?

Comment: Form actions lead to [navigation requests](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#navigation-request), which happen in a [browsing context](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#windows).