# Google Authentication in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, google-oauth, asp.net-core-webapi

In my ASP.NET Core Web API project, I want to authenticate users with google. If I put the sign in endpoint I created in a browser, I'm routed to google for authentication as expected and when I sign in, I'm redirected back to the app as expected. But if I try to send a get request from react to the same endpoint, I get this error

> Access to fetch at 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=<my_clientid>&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5278%2Fsignin-google&scope=openid%20profile%20email&state=' (redirected from 'https://localhost:5278/api/auth/signin-google') from origin 'https://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled

Here my API code:

```
// Program.cs
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", policy =>
    {
        policy
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000", "https://localhost:3000")
            .AllowCredentials();
    });
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddGoogle(options =>
{
    options.ClientId = builder.Configuration["Google:ClientId"]!;
    options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["Google:ClientSecret"]!;
    options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.SaveTokens = true;
})
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        ValidIssuer = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
        ValidAudience = builder.Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(builder.Configuration["Jwt:Key"]!))

    };
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Here's my controller

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet("signin-google")]
public IActionResult SignInGoogle()
{
    var state = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    HttpContext.Session.SetString("GoogleCsrfToken", state);

    var properties = new AuthenticationProperties
    {
        RedirectUri = Url.Action(nameof(GoogleSignInCallback)),
        Items =
        {
            { "state", state }
        }
    };

    return Challenge(properties, GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
}

[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet("google-signin-callback")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GoogleSignInCallback()
{
    try
    {
        var externalLoginInfo = await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        if (externalLoginInfo == null)
            return BadRequest("External login failed.");

        if (!externalLoginInfo.Succeeded)
            return BadRequest("External login failed.");

        var csrfSessionState = HttpContext.Session.GetString("GoogleCsrfToken");
        var receivedCsrfState = externalLoginInfo.Properties.Items["state"];
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(csrfSessionState) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(receivedCsrfState) || csrfSessionState != receivedCsrfState)
            return BadRequest("validation failed.");

        var userEmail = externalLoginInfo.Principal?.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);
        if (userEmail == null)
            return BadRequest("External login failed.");

        var user = await _userRepository.GetFullUserDetailsAsync(userEmail);
        if (user == null)
            return BadRequest("External login failed.");

        if (user.Enable == false)
            return BadRequest($"User account is disabled. Please contact your administrator.");

        if (user.Organization?.Enable == false)
            return BadRequest($"Organization account is disabled. Please contact your administrator.");

        var accessToken = _authService.CreateToken(user);
        if (accessToken == null)
            return BadRequest("Error validating user.");

        return Ok(new { accessToken = accessToken, user = user });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Here's my react app

```
import React from 'react';

function GoogleLogin() {
  const handleGoogleLogin = async () => {
    try {
      // Make a request to your ASP.NET Core backend to initiate the OAuth2 flow
      const response = await fetch('https://localhost:5278/api/auth/signin-google', {
        method: 'GET',
          credentials: 'include',
            
      });

      if (response.status === 200) {
        // Redirect to Google's authentication page as initiated by the server
        window.location.href = response.url;
      } else {
        // Handle error or display a message
        alert('Failed to initiate Google login');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error during Google login:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleGoogleLogin}>Login with Google</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default GoogleLogin;
```

I've allowed all these URLs in the google app registration

[image]

Comment: Could you kindly add `https://localhost:5278/oauth2callback` in `Authorized redirect URIs`? The last section in your last screenshoot, and tell us the test result.

Comment: I got the same error. @JasonPan

Comment: And try this `WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000", 
              "https://localhost:3000",
              "https://accounts.google.com")`.

Comment: I got the same error. I also added ```.AllowAnyOrigin()``` to the cors policy but it didn't work either

Answer (score 1):

I used Azure oauth2 flow to test and reproduce the same error. 
[image]
When using `return Challenge(properties, GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);` to call the oauth2 flow. The fetch just doesn't work. You may re-consider your design [Same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72382892/access-to-fetch-at-https-accounts-google-com-o-oauth2-v2-auth-has-been-blocked#:%7E:text=The%20authentication%20flow%20must%20happen%20in%20a%20visible,redirected%20to%20https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.google.com%2Fo%2Foauth2%2Fv2%2Fauth%3F...%20and%20this%20page%20becomes%20visible.).

A workaroud is using Httpclient in the background to fetch the login endpoint instead, which may meet your demand. Just make another api on top of the endpoint.

```
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet("newapi")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> newapi()
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            var response = await client.GetAsync("https://localhost:7068/signin-google");   //change to your endpoint address 
            return new OkObjectResult(new { Status = response.StatusCode, Url = response.RequestMessage.RequestUri });
        }
   
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet("signin-google")]
        public IActionResult SignInGoogle()
        {
```

js fetch the new api

```
<script>    
       fetch('https://localhost:7068/newapi', {
            method: 'GET',
            }).then(function (body) {return body.text(); })
                .then(function (data) {console.log(data);})
</script>
```

Test result
[image]