# Express.js res.redirect() is not working when using fetch()

Tags: express, redirect, cors, keycloak, openid-connect

I keep getting CORS error when I use `fetch()` to hit endpoint that has `res.redirect()`. It's only problematic when I use `fetch()`, because redirect works fine if I directly type in browser's address bar or use `<a>` tag in frontend code.

---

**Backent Code:**

```js
const corsOptions = {
  origin: function (origin, callback) {
    callback(null, true);
  },
};

/** THIS SENDS FRONTEND (HTML) CODE **/
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "view", "index.html"));
});

/** THIS IS THE REDIRECT ENDPOINT **/
// I tried removing/modifying cors but nothing worked.
router.get("/redirector", cors(corsOptions), (req, res) => {
  res.redirect("https://google.com");
});

app.use(
  bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  }),
  bodyParser.json(),
  router
);

const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log("http://localhost:8080");
});
```

**Frontend Code:**

```html
<body>
   <h1>Home</h1>
   <br />
   <button id="btn">FETCH TO REDIRECT ROUTE</button>

   <script>
      const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
      btn.addEventListener('click', async () => {
         try {
            const response = await fetch('/redirector');
         } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
         }
      });
   </script>
</body>
```

**Visual Representation of above codes:** [image]

---

I know this has to work somehow because NPM packages like [keycloak-connect](https://www.npmjs.com/package/keycloak-connect) implements same [**redirect logic**](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-nodejs-connect/blob/main/middleware/protect.js#L35) and it works just fine. I just can't figure out how to make it work myself.

Comment: you have to handle cors/OPTIONS request first, before doing a redirect

Comment: Why do you want an AJAX request to be redirected to Google?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: google.com does not want to be accessed by a cross-site fetch request from a browser and therefore does not set the `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers. But, as @David already asked, do you really want to fetch the google.com page? This is meant to be loaded by a [navigation request](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#navigation-request), not a fetch request.

Comment: @Kev This cannot work, since `https://google.com` is not configured for CORS.

Comment: The google.com was just an example. I'm trying to implement OIDC manually which requires redirect.

Comment: Specifically about keycloak-connect package I mentioned in the question, its `.protect()` middleware method will auto detect user's login status by checking the request header and redirect user's browser to login page if not logged in. E.G. fetch request from "a.com" to "b.com" => "b.com" expressjs backend middleware `keycloak.protect()` checks if "a.com" user is logged in => If not logged in, "a.com" user will be redirect to "c.com" for login.

Comment: If this is about OIDC, you should not use `fetch`, does this answer your question? [Access to fetch at https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth has been blocked by CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72382892/access-to-fetch-at-https-accounts-google-com-o-oauth2-v2-auth-has-been-blocked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear that you understand what `await fetch('/redirector');` does.  All that does is obtain whatever response comes from `/redirector` for your  Javascript.  It does NOT display anything in the browser.  It does not cause the browser to navigate to a new page.  It just gets data for your Javascript. And, because it's a Javascript request from within a web page, it is subject to CORS limitations which limits where it can be redirected to.

If you want to cause the browser to redirect to a new page, then set `window.location` to the new location you want the browser to go to, don't use `fetch()`.

If you want `fetch()` to follow a redirect (which it does by default), then the redirect has to be to a location that you have cross origin permissions to or it will not be able to follow the redirect.

So, for example, if what you're really trying to accomplish with the `fetch()` call is to get the redirect location and then change the browser page to that location, you can do this:

```
window.location = "/redirector";
```

That will cause the browser to go to `/redirector` which will then successfully see the redirect and tell the browser to go to: `https://google.com`.  Letting the browser follow the redirect in this way will not run into a CORS error.

Comment: How does OIDC login flow implements redirect trigger? Specifically about the keycloak-connect NPM package that I mentioned in the question? When I use that package, the middleware `.protect()` will auto detect user's login status and redirect user's browser to login page which is hosted on another domain. And of course user's client code DOES NOT have redirect logic such as `window.location = ..`

Comment: @Kev - I don't know that code or what it does.  You'd have to look in the code yourself to see how it does what it does.  If it does a form POST (just a browser submitting a form without Javascript being involved), then the browser will follow the redirect response from that automatically.  It's Javascript `fetch()` or `XMLHttpRequest` that doesn't make the browser page change by itself.