# Identity server redirection not working after token expired and getting 302 found

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, cors, identityserver4, http-status-code-302

We have SPA with the IDS 4 and its does not redirect to the login screen post token expires.

Getting below response as blank screen as it does not redirecting to identity server urls.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekf1L.png)

I have configured the CORS in the IDS as well. I have tested the sample MVC client against the same IDS and it working as expected post expiration and redirecting to login page.

But with the SPA that we have its not behaving as expected with this.
Is this related to the headers issue or is there any configuration to be done?

Appreciate any help on this, thanks

And this works perfectly post reload of the page on the 302 error page. So I have tried reloading the page from the client app but still in subsequent login it fails as it has too many cookies already created in the app and throws 413 status code. So I don't want to handle it from frontend by any chance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReactJS sent GET request, responded with 302 redirect, received CORS error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46514522/reactjs-sent-get-request-responded-with-302-redirect-received-cors-error)

Comment: @HeikoTheißen, thanks for the suggestion but we have tried adding the required cors headers to the IDS as we have the control over it, as well as we have updated clientcorsorigins table for the same. But still its just not redirecting to login page. 
Also we tried redirecting manually from the FE but this create too many application cookies and later starts giving 431 error. We have tried one more quickstart mvc client against our IDS but it works properly and redirects to login page properly. I am guessing this is the problem with SPA only?

Comment: The logon flow must happen in a visible browsing context (such as a popup), it cannot be done with `fetch` requests.

Comment: Still not sure if we need to go with the popup logon flow, I have other clients as well using the same IDS 4 and for them its works perfectly without any error but in case of SPA (react app) it just throws CORS error and stops there. Also we have tries the CORS setting as mentioned in the https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/cors.html
Now tried with the sample button on the page and its calling the "Sapmle" controller action and post cookie expiration its just do nothing and stopeed.
Please check the screenshot for the same..