# What is the best way to understand that all redux-forms have been successfully submitted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-form

I have `N` redux-forms on the page and each form has its own submit handler with validation rules.

When user clicks to the Submit button, which is outside of all forms (using [Remote Submit](https://redux-form.com/7.0.4/examples/remotesubmit/)), I trigger submit for each of the forms and want to understand where and how I can catch the event that every form has been submitted *successfully*. In case *all* forms are valid - I need to redirect user to another page.

Could you please give any advice how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On solution:

- Have variables `submittedForms = 0` and `allFormsSubmitted = false` in your initial store state;
- On each form submission, send an action that increases `submittedForms` by 1, and sets `allFormsSubmitted = true` only if `state.submittedForms === N`. Possibly also reset the counter then.
- Have another component listen to changes of `allFormsSubmitted`.

Another is, on each form submission, to read directly the state generated by redux-forms from the store for a flag such as `submitted=true` that is likely there for each form you defined. If all have the flag set, trigger an action that makes `allFormsSubmitted = true`. That way, you don't have to manage the number of forms `N` (susceptible to change).

**Edit**: Example of custom reducer that listens to redux-forms actions:

```
let N = 7;
let defaultState = {
    allFormsSubmitted: false,
    submittedForms: {},
}    

let customReducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {

    case "SUBMIT_SUCCEDED":   // the same as the redux-forms action type - just a string
      state.submittedForms[action.formName] = true;
      if (Object.keys(submittedForms).length === N) {
        state.allFormsSubmitted = true;
      }
      return {...state};

    case "SUBMIT_FAILED":
      state.submittedForms[action.formName] = false;
      state.allFormsSubmitted = false;
      return {...state};

  ...  
  }
}
```

Comment: used the second solution (a little bit modified):

I pass `submitted` flag for each form in Container through `connect` like `xFromSuccessfullySubmitted: hasSubmitSucceeded(CLIENT_INFORMATION_FORM)(state), ...`

and then, in `componentWillReceiveProps()` check `if (nextProps.xFromSuccessfullySubmitted && nextProps.yFromSuccessfullySubmitted && ...) { dispatch allFormsSuccessfullySubmitted() }`

Works well but still not convinced if this is a best solution

Comment: It is a bad idea to dispatch an action in `componentWillReceiveProps`, you risk an infinite loop when all are submitted. Sending actions after you have already reduced is an anti-pattern, too. It must all be reduced at once. Note that you can have several reducers listening to the same action.

Comment: got it. But then I don't understand where should I check that all forms are submitted, in what action? redux-form dispatches `SUBMIT_SUCCEDED` after form submit, so I can't determine if all forms are succeded during submission. Just to doucle confirm: I submit all forms at the same time, and then redux-form dispatches its own actions (which can be `SUBMIT_SUCCEDED` or `SUBMIT_FAILED`

Comment: I added an example of how you can listen to redux-forms actions to react at reduction time. I assume that the actions carry some identifier `formName` of the form.

Comment: Thank you, but it does not answer the question where should I dispatch `redirect` action?

With such reducer we know that `allFormsSubmitted === true` in the state, but this is a reducer where we can't dispatch any actions.

That's why I thought it should be dispatched in `componentWillRecieveProps`

Comment: Actually with this "remote submit" you completely determine the content of the `submit` function, so you are completely in control of the promise inside it. You can just trigger the redirect when the promise is fulfilled, like in the example in https://redux-form.com/7.0.4/examples/remotesubmit/ that throws SubmissionErrors or alerts when there is a success. Replace the alert with the redirect.

Comment: I can't use promis from submit handler because I have many of them (N forms), but only of `submitAllForms` action: 

`function submitAllForms(dispatch) {
    dispatch(submit(CLIENT_INFORMATION_FORM));
    dispatch(submit(CONTRACT_DETAILS_FORM));
}`

So, there is no one general Promise for all forms

Comment: There is one onSubmit-promise for each form and in each of them you can check if all the forms were submitted as discussed before.

Comment: Default `onSubmit` implementation gets only `values`, `dispatch` and `props` parameters. There is no `getState()` function, it means it's impossible to get the actual state at the moment when current onSubmit passes validation. Should I somehow inject `getState` function to `onSubmit`?

Answer (score 1):

> where and how I can catch the event that every form has been submitted
>   successfully and I need to redirect user to another page.

As you are submitting all the forms at the same time , i encountered the same problem , thats how i managed to resolve this issue:

Callback function passed to action creator (createPost)

```
    onSubmit(values){
        this.props.createPost(values, () => {
            this.props.history.push('/');
        });
```

It will not redirect the user unless posts(forms) are successfully posted to the backend api or database , in this case user will be programmatically redirected to the ('/') index.html , You can pass any Route to `this.props.history.push(' ')` as long as that `<Route />` exists in `<BrowserRouter> ('react-router-dom')` the main (index.js) file

Inside action creator , i used [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) to make a post request to backend API and once its successfully posted .then() i passed a callback function to redirect the user

```
    import axios from 'axios';
    export const CREATE_POST = 'create_post';
    const ROOT_URL = 'http://xyz.app.com/api';
    const API_KEY = '?key=xxxxx';

    export function createPost(values, callback) {
        const request = axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/posts${API_KEY}`, values)
            .then(() => callback());
        return {
            type: CREATE_POST,
            payload: request
        };
    }
```

You can read more about programmatically navigation [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123261/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router-v4)

Comment: I agree. Indeed it looks like the remote submit of redux-forms actually gives you complete control of the outcome, like in this example for submission validation: https://redux-form.com/7.0.4/examples/submitvalidation/.