# Access browserHistory in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

How can I access `browserHistory` on redux? I'm passing the `browserHistory` to a `browserRouter` from `react-router`. I want a reducer to listen for an action and the push another url. What's the best solution for this?

Comment: Are you using redux's `connect` to connect your components to the redux store?

Comment: yes, Im connecting it with redux store

Comment: are you using  `withRouter` to wrap your components in order to get the history prop?

Comment: Im using <Router history={browserHistory}> and browserHistory is from react-router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you'll need to have access to the [Route props](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/Route-props) like `history`, `location`, and `match` in a component. You will have these props automatically if the rendered component was created by a `Route` component from react-router. Otherwise, you will need to use `withRouter` from react-router to decorate your component with the Route props.

[Example using withRouter](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/redux-integration):

```
// MyComponent before
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
const MyComponent = (props) => (<div>{props.message}</div>)
export default connect()(MyComponent)

// MyComponent after
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
const MyComponent = (props) => (<div>{props.message}</div>)
export default withRouter(connect()(MyComponent))
```

In the after example, `MyComponent` you will have access to `history` under `props.history` (or `this.props.history` if in a class component).

**After you have access to history** in your component, you can redirect the app using `props.history.push('/a/new/url')`. It sounds like you want to use it in an action to change the state. If that's the case, I recommend passing in your reference to `history` into the action as an argument. Here is an example of an action which creates a new Post and then redirects to a list view of Posts in the same category. Note: I'm using redux-thunk in this example in order to be able to dispatch async actions.

In my [PostForm](https://github.com/julianfresco/udacity.react.p2/blob/912296f9f5f9970fcf85b068c9e6dcc4052f858d/src/components/PostForm.js#L63) component, I create a variable for history:

```
const rrHistory = this.props.history
```

Later, I pass this variable into the `createPost` action when the [Save button is clicked](https://github.com/julianfresco/udacity.react.p2/blob/912296f9f5f9970fcf85b068c9e6dcc4052f858d/src/components/PostForm.js#L138):

```
createPost(model.title, model.body, model.author, model.category, rrHistory)
```

Then in the action code, after some async stuff finishes with the API server, we use the rrHistory variable reference to [redirect to the categories list view](https://github.com/julianfresco/udacity.react.p2/blob/912296f9f5f9970fcf85b068c9e6dcc4052f858d/src/actions/posts.js#L74):

```
rrHistory.push(`/${postCategory}/${newPost.id}`)
```

Note, that this is a working example, but it is far from perfect. You can also check out this SO Answer for other navigation ideas [Programmatically navigate using react router V4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123261/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router-v4/42124328#42124328)

Comment: oh I see. So you are passing the history from the component to an action and then you push the route. Interesting, I will try it.
I was looking for a more 'clean' solution, a way of connecting the store with the actual props of the component, and as history is basically a prop, access it and push the route.

Comment: This is because, I'm creating an authentication system. So whenever you click a button, I use a React-Saga to authenticate the user. If successfull, then redirect to home page... But not sure how should I approach this.

Comment: If the auth call is to the server, it seems like you'd doing something similar to what I did there

Comment: Thanks, Julian. It seems ok, Ill guess Ill try to pass the history reference to an action!

Comment: Tim, as an alternative, you can track your intention to redirect with some piece of state--either in the component's this.state or in the redux store, wherever makes more sense in your app--and use that state value to trigger a [Redirect](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect). For example, in render(): `{ isAuth ? <Redirect to="/auth" /> : ( <MyCompnent /> ) } `

Comment: Wow, I think this is a better solution. I was reading that redux reducers shouldn't have side effects, so my first approach is breaking this rule. So decisiones should be taken on the component or router checking the state first. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Header));
```

Comment: Wrap your component with withRoute.

Comment: your ans is correct if the user is ask that how we will use the browserHistory in component which is not define in route.

But the user ask how to use the browserHistory in redux