# Navigation between the pages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I'm relatively new to `ReactJs`. Consider, we have following code:

**index.js**

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import MyComponent1 from 'path/to/component1'
import MyComponent2 from 'path/to/component2'
import App from './App'

**** 

const WrappedApp = (
  <Router>
    <Route path={App}/>
  </Router>
)

ReactDOM.render(WrappedApp, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import {Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import MyComponent1 from 'path/to/component1'
import MyComponent1 from 'path/to/component2'

    export default class App extends React.Component {
     render() {
       return (
         <Switch>
          <Route path='/' component={MyComponent1}>
          <Route path='/2' component={MyComponent2}>
         <Switch>
        )
     }
```

**Problem**

`MyComponent2` has button, with `onClick`/`submit` should redirect to another  component, that is not specified in router.

How could i archieve that? Im using React Router 4.x

Many thanks for examples and suggestions

Comment: Have you tried to use [`Redirect`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect) component from `react-router v4`?

Comment: Yes i did so, but i cant get it done working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically navigate using react router V4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123261/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router-v4)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127739/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router/44128108#44128108

Comment: You need to specify the route in the router that you need to navigate to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how your component2 is developed, but I see an error here:

```
import MyComponent1 from 'path/to/component1'
import MyComponent1 from 'path/to/component2'
```

Maybe you want to do:

```
import MyComponent2 from 'path/to/component2'
```

And you can also import Link from React Router, like this:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
<Link to="/about">About</Link>
```

See the docs [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/Link.md)

Comment: about imports - thats a typo. But yea, Links was the last thing to come up with.