# How am I supposed to handle both Actions and Routing to different page with React-Router-Redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-redux

I don't think I'm fully understanding how to leverage react-router-redux.  I understand that you can utilize:

```
<header>
    <Link to="/" className="nav-link">Home</Link>  
    <Link to="/about-us" className="nav-link">About Us</Link>
</header>

<main>  
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route exact path="/about-us" component={AboutUs} />
</main>
```

By clicking on the links, the URL changes and different components are loaded.  But how do I programmatically handle a change of component after a certain Action, for instance? I have an action that calls the server, manipulates the state, and then finally should re-route to a new Component.   How does one handle this?

Comment: I guess you possibly need to have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127739/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router/44128108#44128108

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'`

after the action recieves response from server and dispatched the response, listen if response from server is available and return redirect within your render function

```
render () { 
  .... //render logic
if (responseFromServer) {
  <Redirect to='about-us' />
.... // rest of the render function and return statement
}
```

**Update Based on your comment**

I would do that in the about-us component.

```
const resetServerResponse = (serverResponse) => serverResponse = null // depends on typeof serverResponse could be empty string, bool or a set initial state.
......
dispatch(resetServerResponse)
```

so by the time you navigate back to the root `/` , `responseFromServer is falsy and`if (responseFromServer) {` will be skipped and not redirected.

Comment: This works really well but what do you do to reset this variable after being redirected.  If I navigate back to the original component, it automatically redirects me because the `responseFromServer` variable is still active in store.

Comment: Thanks, this worked quite well but after some other searching, I actually preferred the following solution that allows for redirecting outside of the render method.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/42320249/177941

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react-router v4, you can `import { push } from 'react-router-redux'` and use it to dispatch any route like `dispatch(push('/something'))` in your actionCreator. No need to put that in your component logic.

See this example as well to get better clarity.
[ReactRouterAuth Example](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-redux/examples/AuthExample.js)