# Meteor, React Router 4, and Authentication

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-router, react-router-v4, meteor-accounts

I've been scouring the inet trying to find anywhere that defines how to handle authentication in meteor and react router 4 .

Basically, I want certain routes to only be available to authenticated users. Is there any documentation on it?

Aseel

Comment: You can use [Accounts](https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html) to indicate if the user is logged and [redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123261/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router-v4) away from pages that are only allowed to logged in users. Note, that this is no replacement for [securing methods and publications](https://guide.meteor.com/security.html#checklist).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Meteor has a very well developed User Accounts system. It provides ready libraries for OAuth authentication with Twitter, Facebook, etc. as well as a basic but useful UI packages. Check Meteor's official guide [here](https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html) first.

For implementing routing you need to track `Meteor.userId()` and change route via Meteor's reactive system called [Tracker](https://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html). `Meteor.userId()` returns a userId if currently connected user is logged in, and null otherwise. I provide an example code where React Router is used for routing, below. Notice that you'll will also need the [`history`package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history) to be installed and imported while working with React Router v4.

In your client/main.js;

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Tracker } from 'meteor/tracker'
import {onAuthChange, routes} from "../imports/routes/routes";


Tracker.autorun(function(){
    const authenticated = !! Meteor.userId();
    onAuthChange(authenticated);
});

Meteor.startup(() => {
    ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById('app'));
});
```

And in your routes.js file;

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

import Home from './../ui/components/Home';
import Login from './../ui/components/Login';
import NotFound from './../ui/components/NotFound';
import Signup from './../ui/components/Signup';

const history = createBrowserHistory();
const unauthenticatedPages = ['/', '/signup'];
const authenticatedPages = ['/link'];

const publicPage = function  () {
    if (Meteor.userId()) {
        history.replace('/link');
    }
};

const privatePage = function  () {
    if(! Meteor.userId()) {
        history.replace('/');
    }
};

export const routes = (
    <Router history = {history}>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path='/:id' component= {Login} onEnter={publicPage}/>
          <Route exact path='/signup' component={Signup} onEnter={publicPage}/>
          <Route exact path='/link' render={ () => <Home greet='User'/> } onEnter={privatePage} /> 
          <Route component={NotFound}/>
        </Switch>
    </Router>
);

export const onAuthChange = function (authenticated) {
    console.log("isAuthenticated: ", authenticated);
    const path = history.location.pathname;
    const isUnauthenticatedPage = unauthenticatedPages.includes(path);
    const isAuthenticatedPage = authenticatedPages.includes(path);
    if (authenticated && isUnauthenticatedPage) {   // pages: /signup and /
        console.log(`Authenticated user routed to the path /link`);
        history.replace('/link'); 
    } else if (!authenticated && isAuthenticatedPage) {
        console.log(`Unauthenticated user routed to the path /`);
        history.replace('/');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a neat way to have public routes and authenticated routes:
https://gist.github.com/lucnat/643988451c783a8428a2811dbea3d168

- public components are visible by everyone, they use the `PublicLayout`
- authenticated components are visible by authenticated users only -
  they use the `AuthenticatedLayout`

We could have an arbitrary number of layouts. In the example above, there are two layouts - each with it's own navbar.

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to get a more updated method using functional components.
I've tried implementing a conditional check similar to the documentation of React-router.
This was working after giving history.push to a desired route after waiting for `Meteor.loginWithPassword` to complete.
But refreshing the browser ended up rendering login page again.

Meteor is having an intermediate state of `Meteor.loggingIn()`.
Handling this state in the Authentication check fixed this issue.

Feel free to give feedback.

I've created a gist with an implementation for authentication of routes in Meteor - React-router stack with functional components and hooks.

Check this gist with basic structure of the implementation.
https://gist.github.com/rinturj84/0ef61005bf3a4ca5fb665dfc5f77e3d1

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the best idea to do that is to create Multiple separated routers because you can take benefits from using Meteor Reactive-var.

> This is a sample :

```
export default function App() {
    if (Meteor.user()) {
        return (
            <React.StrictMode>
                <Global_Router Client={null} About={About} HomeNavbar={HomePageNav} HomePage_Home={HomePage_Home}
                               HomeFooter={Footer} Homepage_Contacts={Homepage_Contacts}/>
            </React.StrictMode>
        );
    }
    else {
        return(
            <RouterClient/>

        );
    }
```

### Router client

```
export const RouterClient = () => {

    return (
        <Router className="container-fluid">


            <Switch  >
                

                <Route exact path="/Client" >
                    <HomeCLient/>

                </Route>

                <Route path="*">
                    <Redirect to="/Client" />

                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    )
};
```

Respectively,you can create a router for the admin too. In general, that is the most efficient way to do that.