# How to programatically route to a component with react?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am learning react and have a background in angular and have checked the docs and seen a tutorial about routing with react. In angular you can programatically route to components by geting an instance of the router and then calling

```
router.navigate(['/myroute'])
```

I feel like there has to be somthing similar in react, but have seen the docs and do not seen this. Ive just seen references to created a `<Redirect />` component. I would much prefer to programatically route because I assumed one could do this when created a

```
<Switch><Route /> <Route /> ... etc </Switch>
```

So how does one programatically route to components in a similar way that one does with the above angular example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically navigate using react router V4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123261/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router-v4)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Programmatically navigate using react router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079081/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router)

Answer (score 0):

Check out option number 1 here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/42121109/5786795
That's exactly what you're looking for