# onClick from Header component to call function from Other component and render Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am using Reactjs to make pagination and problem I got is that I cannot back to home page if currentPage is changed.

My code structure of `Body` component like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
 .....
}
componentDidUpdate() {
 ....
}
onPageChanged() {
.... 
   this.setState({
        pageChanged: true,
        currentPage: currentPage //1,2,3...
   });
}

render(){
  return(..)
}
```

When `onePageChanged` if I click to Home route, It does not reflect anything. How I can set componentDidUpdate to return the first page if I click on `Header`?

my `Header` component:

```
<h1 className="site-title">
   <Link to={CelestialSettings.path}>My Website</Link>
</h1>
```

I am thinking about using onClick on `Header component` like this:

`<Link onClick={backhomepage()}>My Website</Link>`

but I do not know how use.

Any suggestion? Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you using `react-router-dom`? Can you add all your code logic to the question?

Comment: Hi @DineshPandiyan. Yes. I am using react-router-dom. Sorry the code is so long so I cannot post here. I just want to know is possible to call function to return homepage from `Header`

Comment: You need to programmatically navigate to a new page. You can use `history.push()` for your case. Take a look at this answer - [programmatically-navigate-using-react-router-v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123261/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router-v4)