# React JS: Call action on form and redirect to specified page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I have a React component with a form that has an action like so:

```
<center>
    <Form
        action={`/api/sets/`}
        method="post"
        onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>

        <Button color="primary" type="submit">
            Finish
        </Button>
    </Form>
</center >
```

The `onSubmit` function looks like this:

```
onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    window.location = "/workout-history";
    e.target.submit()
}
```

The action to `/api/sets/` happens after clicking the button and the `onSubmit` function does get called but the page isn't redirected. In the post to `/api/sets` I am returning status 204 so that shouldn't determine where it goes. I am guessing it's possible the function gets called first then the action gets called. Any ideas on how to call the forms action and redirect the page elsewhere?

Comment: if you want to form does the action why do you have  `e.preventDefault()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use import react-router-dom for redirecting.

```
import { Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'


onSubmit = () => {
      return <Redirect to='/target' />
  }
```

you can view more in : 
https://medium.com/@anneeb/redirecting-in-react-4de5e517354a

Comment: That's still not working. It's doing the exact same thing. The function gets called but the page doesn't redirect. I'm not sure why.

Comment: Can you try change your button finish ? with :         <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

Answer (score 0):

The answer you are looking for is [probably this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42124328/2627022).

Prefer using `withRouter` HOC and call `history.push('/new-location')` in `onSubmit` function.