# How to remove active class when click another toggle button in React.js?

Tags: reactjs

In React.js, I have page link menus and 3 toggle buttons in `header.js`.

All toggles buttons have `div` layer when clicked.

What I am trying to make is...

1. When click a toggle button, other toggle buttons and layer has to be removed class `active`
2. When click page link menu(menu1, menu2, menu3), all toggle buttons and layers has to be removed class `active`

What do I need to change the code ?

This is what I tried so far now.

Please help.

DEMO : https://codesandbox.io/s/49io4

*header.js*

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Header() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [show2, setShow2] = useState(false);
  const [show3, setShow3] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (show) {
      document.body.classList.add("bodyRemoveScroll");
    } else {
      document.body.classList.remove("bodyRemoveScroll");
    }
  }, [show]);
  const onToggleClick = () => setShow(!show);
  const onToggleClick2 = () => setShow2(!show2);
  const onToggleClick3 = () => setShow3(!show3);

  return (
    <div className="header">
      {/* <NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink> */}
      /<NavLink to="/menu1">menu1</NavLink>/
      <NavLink to="/menu2">menu2</NavLink>/<NavLink to="/menu3">menu3</NavLink>/
      <button onClick={onToggleClick} className={show ? "active" : ""}>
        toggle1
      </button>
      <nav className={`layer1 ${show ? "active" : ""}`}>layer 1</nav>/
      <button onClick={onToggleClick2} className={show2 ? "active" : ""}>
        toggle2
      </button>
      <nav className={`layer2 ${show2 ? "active" : ""}`}>layer 2</nav>/
      <button onClick={onToggleClick3} className={show3 ? "active" : ""}>
        toggle3
      </button>
      <nav className={`layer3 ${show3 ? "active" : ""}`}>layer 3</nav>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, you should unselect other values once you have clicked on some item. Other (preferable) option would be to have 1 state variable, where you will store your current active button id

```
const onToggleClick = () => {
  setShow(!show)
  setShow2(false);
  setShow3(false);
};

const onToggleClick2 = () => {
  setShow(false)
  setShow2(!show2);
  setShow3(false);
};

const onToggleClick3 = () => {
  setShow(false)
  setShow2(false);
  setShow3(!show3);
};
```

So example below looks prettier to me

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Header() {
  const [active, setActive] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    if (active) {
      document.body.classList.add("bodyRemoveScroll");
    } else {
      document.body.classList.remove("bodyRemoveScroll");
    }
  }, [active]);

  const onSetActiveMenuItem = (item) => {
    if (item !== active){
      setActive(item);
    }
    else {
      setActive(''); // handle click on currently active item
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="header">
      {/* <NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink> */}/
      <NavLink to="/menu1">menu1</NavLink>/<NavLink to="/menu2">menu2</NavLink>/
      <NavLink to="/menu3">menu3</NavLink>/
      <button onClick={() => onSetActiveMenuItem('item1')} className={active === 'item1' ? "active" : ""}>
        toggle1
      </button>
      <nav className={`layer1 ${active === 'item1' ? "active" : ""}`}>layer 1</nav>/
      <button onClick={() => onSetActiveMenuItem('item2')} className={active === 'item2' ? "active" : ""}>
        toggle2
      </button>
      <nav className={`layer2 ${active === 'item2' ? "active" : ""}`}>layer 2</nav>/
      <button onClick={() => onSetActiveMenuItem('item3')} className={active === 'item3' ? "active" : ""}>
        toggle3
      </button>
      <nav className={`layer3 ${active === 'item3' ? "active" : ""}`}>layer 3</nav>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This works perfect. I have one more question, how to remove active class on toggle button when click  menu1, menu2, menu3 page link ?

Comment: @user1833620 I see you have already done that on your codesandbox, am I right? You have just added `onClick={resetToggle}` if you need to set navLink inactive when you click on buttons, then you need to update your current URL, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123261/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router-v4) answer to do that

Comment: Yes. I tried  onClick={resetToggle} with your example :)  Thank you Works Goood :)

Comment: I have updated my answer, you can check the second part and use 1 state variable as you shouldn't have two active items in one moment

Answer (score 2):

I suggest only using one "show" useState, and specify a "type" useState to further clarify layer:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Header() {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
  const [type, setType] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    if (show) {
      document.body.classList.add("bodyRemoveScroll");
    } else {
      document.body.classList.remove("bodyRemoveScroll");
    }
  }, [show]);
  const onToggleClick = (type) => {
    setShow(!show);
    setType(type);
  };

  return (
    <div className="header">
      {/* <NavLink to="/">Home</NavLink> */}/
      <NavLink to="/menu1">menu1</NavLink>/<NavLink to="/menu2">menu2</NavLink>/
      <NavLink to="/menu3">menu3</NavLink>/
      <button
        onClick={() => onToggleClick("layer1")}
        className={show ? "active" : ""}
      >
        toggle1
      </button>
      <nav className={`layer1 ${show && type === "layer1" ? "active" : ""}`}>
        layer 1
      </nav>
      /
      <button
        onClick={() => onToggleClick("layer2")}
        className={show ? "active" : ""}
      >
        toggle2
      </button>
      <nav className={`layer2 ${show && type === "layer2" ? "active" : ""}`}>
        layer 2
      </nav>
      /
      <button
        onClick={() => onToggleClick("layer3")}
        className={show ? "active" : ""}
      >
        toggle3
      </button>
      <nav className={`layer3 ${show && type === "layer3" ? "active" : ""}`}>
        layer 3
      </nav>
    </div>
  );
}
```