# Redirect doesn't work after onClick in React

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router

I have a problem with `<Redirect />` from `react-router-dom`. It does not redirect the user to the given path.

```
    const getCourse = () => {
            console.log('gg');
            <Redirect to={"/courses/" + id} /> //
        }
...
    <div className="menu__course" onClick={() => getCourse()}>
```

In console I see 'gg' so function is called but my path doesn't change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<Redirect />` needs to be returned by the outer function (i.e.: the react component)

Instead, your getCourse callback should setButtonClicked(true) and you should do something like:

```js
if (buttonClicked) {
    return <Redirect to... />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The  Redirect component works when it's mounted to the virtual dom.
You can't call it from a function. The following question and answer go in depth on how to solve your problem

[Programmatically navigate using react router V4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123261/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router-v4)

Answer (score 0):

You could refer to something like this

```
        const [course, setCourse] = useState()     

        const getCourse = () => {
            console.log('gg');
            setCourse("gg")
        }

        if(course === "gg") return <Redirect to={"/courses/" + id} />




    return <div className="menu__course" onClick={() => getCourse()}>
```

or if u wish to redirect from func itself use

```
        const getCourse = () => {
            console.log('gg');
            history.push(your-route)
        }
```