# Programmatically navigate using with React router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router

With `react-router` I can use the `Link` element to create links which are natively handled by react router.

I see internally it calls `this.context.transitionTo(...)`.

I want to do a navigation. Not from a link, but from a dropdown selection (as an example). How can I do this in code? What is `this.context`?

I saw the `Navigation` mixin, but can I do this without `mixins`?

Comment: Are you not able to at least update to `react-router-dom@5`? You could use the `history` object and issue an imperative navigation. Actually NM, RRDv4 has access to `history` it seems. V4 and v5 are basically the same version, but I suggest *strongly* you should bump to v5 if you can. Please edit your post to share a [mcve] so we can see what your code is doing.

Comment: It seems that https://stackoverflow.com/a/42124328/8690857 might be what you are looking for.